# Rappelons-nous, qui avons bonne mémoire, l'année 1822

Tags: grammaire

> Rappelons-nous, qui avons bonne mémoire, l'année 1822.

C'est la première phrase du livre *La vie, la mort, la vie* d'Erik Orsenna, de l'Académie française. On se dit que ce type de personne fait attention à son français, mais la phrase me dérange un peu.

La phrase suivante aurait été irréprochable :

> Rappelons-nous, **nous** qui avons bonne mémoire, l'année 1822.

Y a-t-il une règle qui permet d'omettre le deuxième *nous* ? S'agit-il d'une licence littéraire ? Avez-vous des exemples similaires ?

Answer (score 3):

Quelques fois le pronom peut être omis et implicite, quand par exemple il y a plusieurs actions pour un même sujet, ou quand on se réfère à la même chose, (et c'est ici facilité par la mise en apposition), mais cela fait très très littéraire. Et c'est certainement l'effet qu'a voulu produire Orsenna. Il ne cherche pas à être irréprochable, il cherche à faire un effet de style avec une construction vieillie. Il a voulu éviter la répétition un peu lourde de "nous".

Il aurait pu écrire aussi par exemple:

> Nous sommes fatigués, qui avons fait la guerre

.Ou:

> Je les ai vu, qui ont marché longtemps.

C'est une tournure poétique. La phrase est grammaticalement correcte, même si incroyablement peu usitée. On devrait presque rajouter le tag [poétique](/questions/tagged/po%c3%a9tique)